# Can one prevent Error List from showing?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does anyone know how to **prevent** the Error List from showing after a build fails?

I have the "*Always show Error List if build finished with errors*" checkbox **unchecked**, but when the build finishes, with an error, the !@#&!@# Error List still shows.

Does this checkbox even do anything?

I'm running VS2015.2.

[image]

UPDATE: it does seem to depend on the type of project being built. i can't determine exactly what the cause is, but for me at least it seems to be related to building a class library project containing an .edmx file with associated .tt templates.

Comment: I too am having the same issue. It is annoying. I posted the same question 30 minutes after you, then deleted it.